# S3 Bucket policy to ensure that EMails stored by SES are encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

I have a S3 bucket into which SES stores eMails. I want to ensure via an S3 bucket policy, that the stored objects are encrypted.

The method described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html) does not work. The uploaded objects do not seem to set `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` is not set, also encryption is enabled in SES.

There are other tags, for example `x-amz-meta-x-amz-matdesc` contains the KMS key id. So I tried:

```
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:PutObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotLike": {
      "x-amz-meta-x-amz-matdesc": "kms_cmk_id*"
  }
}
```

But this policy is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the policy that you can use to make sure the data is encrypted. Below policy will works only when your emails are encrypted. Check this guide for encrypting the email in SES.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ses.html#services-ses-overview

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PutObjPolicy",
   "Statement":[{
         "Sid":"DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Principal":"*",
         "Action":"s3:PutObject",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption":"aws:kms"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: That is the exact policy from the link I provided. Unfortantly it does not work in combination with SES encryption.

Comment: When creating the SES rule set: Could not write to bucket: <my-bucket> (Request ID: 35d6ce04-4a8e-11e6-b780-c79a3c67756e)

Comment: It still does not work. SES does not set that header when storing emails.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post. Encrypting the SES message won't set s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption. For example if you sent cipher text to s3 that was encrypted client side the s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption header wouldn't be set. Since the header isn't set, you can't upload the SES message, even though the message is encrypted. Of course setting this is going to encrypt the cipher text.  Not sure on what you are trying to achieve, but you could send the plain text SES message to s3 and rely on s3 to encrypt it, that would set the http header in the policy below.

You need to set the encryption policy when uploading to s3, I believe that is the issue.

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2R0GFOXFYEDM5/How-to-Prevent-Uploads-of-Unencrypted-Objects-to-Amazon-S3

```
 {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
     "Statement": [
           {
                "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
                "Condition": {
                        "StringNotEquals": {
                               "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                         }
                }
           },
           {
                "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
                "Condition": {
                        "Null": {
                               "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": true
                        }
               }
           }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: What I am trying to do: I am trying to prevent anyone from accidently storing unencrypted emails in the bucket. Now you say, I could "rely on S3 to encrypt it". I can not find any information on how to do this with SES EMails. Do you have any further information about that? The policy you are posting does not work because, as you said, SES does not set the header.

Comment: What's your use case? Are the users manually uploading emails to S3? Is it some kind of automated process? Do the emails need to be encrypted at all times or just when in S3?

Comment: The s3 bucket stores emails from ses, which i configure to store incoming Mails in s3. I will add further Mails in the future, and i want to prevent myself from configuring ses so that they are stored unencrypted. The Mails are not encrypted when they come in the ses SMTP Server.